Sum and difference of integers on a blackboard
I got this question from my tutor as a bonus question to think about. I am currently taking a course in combinatorics and I have seen similar blackboard problems, but for this one I have not found a good approach yet.
Problem
The integers $1,\dots,n$ are initially written on a blackboard. Select two integers $a$ and $b$, erase them, and replace them with $a+b$ and $2|a-b|$. This operation can be used indefinitely often.
For each $n$, find the biggest natural number $N$, such that $N$ zeroes are written on the blackboard after a finite amount of operations.
My first progress
The difficult thing about this problem is that it is hard to check if a found $N$ is maximal for a given $n$.
I tried looking at small cases to hopefully find a pattern. Exodd and abacaba found a bigger $N$ for the cases $n=3$, $n=4$ and $n=5$:

$n=2$: $N=0$. There is no way to get a zero there.
$n=3$: $N=2$. Found by Exodd.
$n=4$: $N=3$. Found by abacaba.
$n=5$: $N=3$. Found by abacaba.
$n=6$: $4 \le N \le 5$. I got $4$ with a sequence (see in the comments) and $6$ is not possible, because it can't be all zeroes.

My sequence for $n=6$ is: 123456 -> 135246 (re-sorted) -> 135 (32) 00 (with abacaba's sequence) -> 445 (32) 00 -> 085 (32) 00 -> 8 (16) 5 (32) 00 -> 588 (16) (32) 0 -> 05 (16) (16) (32) 0 -> 050 (32) (32) 0 -> 0500 (64) 0
Current progress
Currently we have a method to get a zero with three digits in a sequence:

123 -> 233 -> 206 -> 808 -> 00 (16).
246 -> 466 -> 4 (12) 0 -> (16) (16) 0 -> (32) 00.

Moreover, two digits $a$ and $b$ will be the same after the operation, iff they are of the form $(a,3b)$ with $a \ge b$. (This is a result if you assume wlog that $a \ge b$ and then set $a+b = 2|a-b|$.)

"I've looked at the small cases up to $n=5\ldots$" and what did you find? How did you look? Was it a brute force search of the state space?

For $n=2$ it is trivial, as there is no way to get a zero. So $N=0$. In the case $n=3$ I cancelled out the odd integers, and got $N=1$, because you end up with an odd and an even digit. For $n=4$ or $n=5$ I tried to brute force and got $N = 2$ for both of them

This is is the sort of thing to include in your post! Have a look at this.

for $n=3$ you get $N=2$ because
123 - 233 - 206 - 808 - 00 16

When $N = 5$ i think there is a very long sequence that can get 3 zeros. 12345-> 24445 -> 24580 -> 45680 -> 26890 -> 88890 -> (16) 8900 -> 2 (16) (17) 0 0 -> 2 2 (33) 0 0 -> 4 (33) 0 0 0.

When $N = 4$ there is a way to get 3 zeros. 1234 -> 2334 -> 2460, then use @Exodd's method on 246 to get two zeros. 246 -> 466 -> 4 (12) 0 -> (16) (16) 0 -> (32) 0 0.

Source of problem?

Did you catch that powerful idea?  If we can sequences of previous results, then we can simply reuse previous steps..

@SarveshRavichandranIyer My tutor gave me some problems to think about, and this was one of them. Unfortunately I do not know, where this problem is from.

@nickalh Yes, I just found a way for $n=6$ to get 4 zeroes using Exodd's method: 123456 -> 135246 (re-sorted) -> 135 (32) 00 (with abacaba's sequence) -> 445 (32) 00 -> 085 (32) 00 -> 8 (16) 5 (32) 00 -> 588 (16) (32) 0 -> 05 (16) (16) (32) 0 -> 050 (32) (32) 0 -> 0500 (64) 0

I have the impression that from any 3 non zero numbers you can always get a zero

$n=5, N=3$ seems a bit odd. Are you sure that $N=4$ isn’t possible for $n=5$?

I got $n=7,N=5$. Quite a long sequence. But at this stage, only a general strategy or algorithm is useful rather than finding the number for specific cases. It's a shame that this question is closed. So interesting. Sheep, I would suggest you to try to request reopening this in meta. I have no luck getting my requests resolved in my favor, else I would have attempted it

some other info. Given 2 numbers it is interesting to understand if they can ever produce a zero. Call any such couple of numbers a nice couple. You get that $(a,b)$ is a nice couple iff $(ka,kb)$ is a nice couple, since common factors get through the operation. Moreover, if you start from a couple with different parity, they will never reach a zero. One can compute all coprime nice couples by starting from $(1,1)$ and going back. You get $(1,3)$ that we are currently using, then $(5,7)$, $(9,19)$, $(3, 17)$ etc.

As an addendum, if $(a,b)$ is a nice coprime couple, then it can be generated only by the nice coprime couples $(2a-b,2a+b)$ and $(2b-a,2b+a)$ when their components are positive

@Exodd Thanks, that is really helpful! With this information one can optimize $n=7$, as there are three nice couples: $(1,3), (2,6)$ and $(5,7)$. Then the sequence is 1326574 -> 0008 (16) (32) 4 -> 00488 (16) (32) -> 0004 (16) (16) (32) -> 00004 (32) (32) -> 000004 (64), which leads to $N=5$, as Srini has pointed out earlier. Another thing I noticed: Every nice couple $(a,b)$ I tried so far left a zero and a power of two at the end.
